# php require relative path

Tags: php, relative-path, include-path

When I require any PHP file in my index page I see an error:

my config file :

```
define( "APP_ROOT", realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) ).'/' );
```

my includes/require file put :

```
localhost/test/includes/
```

failing code and error :

```
require_once(APP_ROOT .'includes/test1.php');
require_once(APP_ROOT .'includes/test2.php');

failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\includes\test.php on line 38
```

What is my problem? How can I fix this for any relative path.

Comment: Try to print out `APP_ROOT .'includes/test1.php'` to check whether the directory is correct

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.realpath.php

Comment: I don't think the error generated form here ....  what is on `on line 38` ???

Comment: Line 38 is probably the include line as the error is that the file wasn't found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your file is being called from /test/includes, so APP_PATH is C:\xampp\htdocs\test\includes\, so your trying to require C:\xampp\htdocs\test\includes\includes/test1.php and so forth.

Echo APP_PATH and see what it prints.

Your better off making all the includes relative to each other, and then you only have to play games importing a single common.php file from your index.php

Comment: Then you probably need to include app_root . 'test/includes/test1.php' and so on

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `realpath(dirname(__DIR__))`